# Method invoke no functional with the control label C#

Tags: frameworks, label, invoke, .net-4.8

I have a question :
I'm developing a program in C# that use the Framework version 4.8 and Visual Studio Community 2022 (64bits).

I need to use the class "Backgroudworker" for reasons of performances and for no stopping my app but also, for display a counter a using the control label.

I read that it was necessary to use the "Invoke" method of the "Label" control but that does not work because it does not exist with version 4.8 of the .NET Framework.

Could you tell me which method replaces "Invoke" with the new version of the framework?

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Best regards.

I tried to display the "Invoke" method in the "Label" field but it does not exist